# Can you Modify or Increase the Size of the Recent Apps List?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, task-management, multitasking, recents-screen

I tend to rely on Recent Apps list to bounce between apps I use most often, as a sort of day-long history, for example. Is there a trick to increasing how many apps are listed in the default Recent Apps list (long-press home > Recent Apps)? I believe it's limited to 8, is there a trick/app which would increase it? **Picture the PC Alt-Tab menu when you have 10+ programs open.** Perhaps it makes more sense on a phone (from a resources perspective) to limit the number of apps on the Recent Apps list.

I'm not looking for a task-killing app, but a task-switching app. Would this be solved if I looked into a tasker app?

<s>**EDIT1:** Using Advanced Task Killer as a switching app is a workaround. Still looking for an answer that literally increases the number of apps shown after long-pressing home.</s>

**EDIT2:** Another very similar question had [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/can-you-get-of-the-running-applicaiton-on-adroid-for-the-purpose-of-activating-th/2035#2035), which is more convenient than Advanced Task Killer, IMO. Still, I would prefer a solution that would incorporate long-pressing Home, like the original Recent Apps list.

Comment: I've tried AppSwipe! v2, Task Switcher & Switcher Widget, and none of them show all of my running apps (as shown by a long press on the Home button), so I'd discount them all right off the bat.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of my question : 
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/can-you-get-of-the-running-applicaiton-on-adroid-for-the-purpose-of-activating-th

Comment: I'm just going to learn to live with a recent apps list with just 8 apps in it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Task Killer can be configured so that it always stays on the Notification Bar. And it can also be configured such that the "Default Click Action" will "Switch To" the application. I found it works good enough as a task switcher.

Comment: Interesting... I stopped using that app but I may try re-purposing it for that.

Comment: interesting

Answer (score 2):

If you have rooted your device and use a 'Villain' rom, you can find an option to change this setting in Villain Settings > Input settings > Long-press home settings.

Realise you might not have this rom but it's worth a mention!

Answer (score 1):

The closest things I've seen so far are [More Recent](http://www.goodandevo.net/2010/05/how-to-see-15-recent-apps-instead-of-6-on-htc-evo-4g.html) and [Visual Task Switcher](http://www.goodandevo.net/2010/10/visual-task-switcher-does-what-it-says-on-htc-evo-4g.html)

It doesn't appear that either of these uses long-press-home, but an alternate key-sequence.

I've seem more mentions for More Recent.

The Good and Evo review of Visual Task Switcher sounded like it's lacking somewhat.

(I have not personally used either)

Comment: I don't see More Recent in the market and Visual Task Switcher does not seem to play nicely with HTC Sense UI.

Comment: As far as I know, More Recent is NOT in the market.  Bummer that Sense and VTS don't get along.

Comment: I realize this still doesn't address the original objective, but just came across Itching Thumb.  Comments say it works with EVO and and so, presumably, HTC Sense.