# How do I find a list of open applications / switch to open applications

Tags: applications, task-management, multitasking

Where can I find a list of open applications ? Is it possible to switch to them using that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long pressing on the home button will bring up the six most recently accessed apps and you can switch them. How many stay in the memory depends on your phone and the size off the app. Android keeps all opened apps in the memory until it needs space.  There are countless apps that show what apps are running in your memory. Search the market for "app manager" or "task manager".  One I particularly like is [Smart Bar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/smart-taskbar-%28sidebar%29/com.smart.taskbar).

Comment: I've tried the long press home key, but that shows recently accessed apps, not recently open apps. Will have a look at @gary's suggestions as well. Thanks

Comment: @Sathya I mentioned a couple potentially helpful apps... @matt makes a good point to just search "app manager" & "task manager". You may try some other ones out that end up working better for you. Post back what you find.

Comment: See this similar question. Lots of good suggestions and discussion: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2018/can-you-get-a-list-of-the-running-applicaiton-on-adroid-for-the-purpose-of-activa  Sorry for being short. I'm typing on my droid.

Comment: @Matt thanks for that link, I'll explore those apps.

Comment: @Matt Smart Taskbar works great. I'll accept this, please edit your answer.. to include Smart Taskbar.

Comment: And the list of apps isn't always accurate; when I access gmail from the notication bar, switch to another app, and bring up recent apps to go back to gmail.... it's not there. Aaaaargh! I can't believe I actually think something from WinXP works better!

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis Yeah, it's my experience too that the "recently accessed" list doesn't always show the app I just accessed. Really weird behaviour! Do you know if it's that it shows only the apps that I've actually launched via their own shortcuts, or what's the deal?

Answer (score 2):

- As Matt mentions, you can long-press the home button to see the 6 or 8 most recent apps.
- I've also seen [Itching Thumb](http://www.appbrain.com/app/itching-thumb-%28task-manager%29/com.bw.flipit) suggested here before.
- As Matt also mentions, there are task manager apps. One is [Advanced Task Killer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/advanced-task-killer/com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller) (or [Advanced Task Killer Froyo](http://www.appbrain.com/app/advanced-task-killer-froyo/com.rechild.advancedtaskkillerfroyo) even) which can be configured to switch to the open app rather than killing it.

BTW, if you search for whether you should use ATK to kill apps, you'll see a lot of advice telling you it's not needed for Froyo. I had not heard of ATK Froyo until now, so I don't know what makes it different than the original ATK.

Comment: I'm on Gingerbread, Nexus S if that matters @Matt.