# Application to switch among multiple running applications

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have Samsung galaxy ace with android 2.2 mobile.

Is there any way or any application so i can run many applications simultaneously and i can switch among them?

**Why do i need this.**

1. When i surf facebook(or any other
   application), and i click on a link.
   I am suppose to wait until the page
   gets opened then i read it pess back
   button to reach on previous button.
   If i press previous button in
   between i'll lost page which was
   being loaded.
2. If i read some sms, and i have to
   search the meaning of a word in dictionary, i
   would have to exit from sms box.

Comment: Also see: ["Can you get a list of the RUNNING applications on Android for the purpose of activating them?"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2018)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Case #1: You can get back to recently used apps by holding down the home key until a menu appears, and then selecting the app you want to return to.

Case #2: Press the home button and open your dictionary app, and then use the method in #1 to return to messaging.

This works if you don't have too many apps open, since the memory is limited and if you open too many apps, android will close them from the background.

The important distinction is that the home key does not quit the app but exists to the launcher, and the back button exits the app.

Comment: for second point, is there any sms addon/extension which can help me to see words meaning directly while i am reading the sms, instead of switching to another application then manually searching

Comment: @articlestack, I don't think the stock messaging app can be extended this way, but maybe some third-party messaging apps could do this. Don't know of any though.

Answer (score 3):

Onik is correct in suggesting the built in task switcher but if you search "task switcher" in the market you will find a number of apps that might help, I suggest picking something light weight and intuitive.

From personal experience I can easily suggest QuickDesk or Wave Launcher.

QuickDesk will bring up a virtual home screen whenever/wherever. You can assign your favourite apps, shortcuts etc and it can show a scrollbar of recently run apps.

I recently switched to Wave Launcher and love it. It's highly configurable, light and intuitive, mimicking the gesture activate ribbon in Palm's WebOS. With a flick of your thumb or finger, you can bring up your favourite app, a recently run app, shortcut, or app draw overlay, all without leaving your current app (as long as you back out of whatever you're in). It is regulary updated and has brought many new features and improvements. Take a little time to experiment and tweak it and I thin you'll be very happy.

Best of luck.

Comment: Wave launcher is good but its gesture area cause problem to me when i type sms. QuickDesk might be good. But i dont try since developer has stopped its further development & support. One more what i found is multi task switcher. I dint try it now but it seems good from its reviws

Comment: @articlestack Have a good play with the options. I had a similar problem. Took me a while to get it just right but you can customise the gesture area to whatever size and position you want.